# Clifford algebra vs 'universal' clifford algebra?

Tags: definition, clifford-algebras

In (Lounesto, Ablamowicz; 2012; pg307) Hahn defines a Clifford algebra as follows (almost verbatim):

> Let $M=(M,q)$ with associated bilinear form $b$ be a quadratic module
>   over $R$. A *Clifford algebra* of $M$ is a pair $C(M)=(C(M),\gamma)$
>   such that
>
> (a) $C(M)$ is an $R$-algebra and
>
> (b) $\gamma:M\rightarrow C(M)$ is an $R$-module map satisfying
>   $\gamma(x)^2=q(x)1_C$ and
>   $\gamma(x)\gamma(y)+\gamma(y)\gamma(x)=b(x,y)1_C$ for all $x$ and $y$
>   in $M$, and
>
> (c) $(C(M),\gamma)$ is "minimal" (in the sense of a universal mapping
>   property) with respect to (a) and (b).

Now I have also come across the term of a 'universal Clifford algebra' in e.g. (Porteous, 1995; pg130). Is the above definition defining a 'universal Clifford algebra' or a general (i.e. possibly non-universal) Clifford algebra. In either case how would we change it so it defines the other?